# C# referring to object variable with string

Tags: c#

Hi in Actionscript I may refer to a variable within an object thusly

```
objectName["variableName"] = "Some value";
```

How would I do the equivalent in c#

thanks

Comment: The variable names match the column names in the db so instead of matching each up I just want to loop the column names and fill the appropriate variable

Comment: Seems you have something in mind to accomplish. What's your C# code so far?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is not part of the language & is provided in the framework.
Use [`Dictionary<Key, Value>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, string> myData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

myData.Add("first", "stack");
myData.Add("second", "overflow");

Console.WriteLine(myData["first"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class x{
  public method1() {
    var objectName = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    objectName["variableName"] = "Some value";
  }
}
```

Or, use strongly-typed properties (safer and fast running), recommended where you know variable names at compile-time.

```
public class Person{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}
}

// and use it as follows in your functions

var person1 = new Person() {
  Name = "Fred",
  Age = 21,
};

// again, to demonstrate different syntax to do same thing
var person2 = new Person();
person2.Name = "Danny";
person2.Age = 2;
person2.Age = "x";  // won't compile - expects int, hence safer
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you genuinely mean an object you want:

```
objectName.variableName = "Some value";
```

If you want a Map (also known as an associative array) your best solution is a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>()
d["variableName"] = "Some value";
```

Answer (score 0):

What type of variable?  It sounds like a dictionary/hashtable is most suited.  These have index operators `[]`, so the syntax will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't have "objects with variables".  C# objects have properties which are accessed like MyObject.PropertyName.

Comment: Er... yes it does; they're called fields, but that is what they are: object-level variables.

Comment: I've never heard anyone reference a field as an "object variable"

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is a key-value collection. A Dictionary is C# implementation of this. Note that a dictionary only allows for *unique*  keys. You can use it generically so you can use it like this.

```
Dictionary<string, string> myValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myValues.Add("variableName", "variableValue");
```

or

```
Dictionary<string, int> familySizes = new Dictionary<string, int>();
familySizes.Add("simpsons", 5);
```

As you can see you can choose what datatypes you use.